# How to define a final variable (mutable constant) in C++?

Tags: c++, final

How do I define a constant in C++, that points to a mutable object?

If I declare

```
static const CMyClass* IMPL;
```

and assign

```
const CMyClass* CSomeClass::IMPL = new CMyClass;
```

then I can only call `const` functions on the object. Its internals are locked. This is not what I want.

If I leave off the `const` qualifier, I can reassign the pointer `IMPL`, so it isn’t protected as a constant anymore, which it should be. `final` seems to be applicable only to functions in C++. Is there an equivalent to a Java’s `final` variables in C++?

Comment: So you want the pointer to be not assignable but the pointed to object to be assignable?

Comment: Even if you don't leave off `const` you can reassign the pointer `IMPL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between const int\*, const int \* const, and int const \*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

```
class CMyClass{};

class CSomeClass{
    static CMyClass* const IMPL;
};

CMyClass* const CSomeClass::IMPL = new CMyClass;
```

## Explanation

`const` in C++ is not the exact analog of Java's `final`.

- In Java the `final` specifier applies to the variable and means that the variable cannot be reassigned (though the object referred to by that variable can still be modified).
- Unlike that, in C++ `const` applies to the type. Since C++ has pointers it is important to distinguish the type of the pointer variable itself and the type of the object to which that variable would refer. Depending on where you put your `const` it applies to the former or the latter. The other answers elaborate on that in more detail.

Comment: Could you add some comments......I don't think he understands that this could fix his problem, because he does not know what he is looking at

Answer (score 14):

You have to place the `const` at the right place in the declaration. The rule is: `const` applies to the thing immediately to the left, unless it's at the left edge itself, when it applies to the right.

Therefore, these two are (mutable) pointers to a constant integer:

```
const int * p;
int const * p;
```

This is a constant pointer to a (mutable) integer:

```
int * const p;
```

And these are constant pointers to a constant integer:

```
const int * const p;
int const * const p;
```

Answer (score 5):

1) Pointer to a const element: `const T* ptr`

2) Const pointer to a mutable element: `T* const ptr`

3) Const pointer to a const element: `const T* const ptr`

What you want here is 2) : const pointer to a mutable element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out 3). It makes clear to me that all my constants (what I thought they were) are immutable, but still exchangable!

Comment: You're welcome @Paramaeleon. Good luck and happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

C++'s 'final' is not related to constants, it's for virtual functions: it indicates a virtual function is the end of the line, and won't be overridden.

Use const_cast to ignore const and call a const method on the object:

```
const CMyClass* CSomeClass::IMPL = new CMyClass;
const_cast <CMyClass *> (CSomeClass::IMPL) -> someNonConstMethod ();
```

But this "feels" wrong; you're trying to protect your variable by making it constant, so overriding const doesn't seem like what you really want.  Maybe:

- Instead of protecting the variable with const, make member variables private so outsiders can't tinker with them.  Then provide accessor functions (non-const) to allow them to be manipulated in allowable ways.
- If you have member variables that need to be altered from const methods, mark them as 'mutable'.
- To protect an object from being deleted outside your control, make its destructor private.